# tensoflow word2vec_basic input-output placeholders

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec

I am a  newbie in tensorflow. I am trying to understand the [word2vec_basic](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) script.

At the beggining it defined input and output.

```
train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
```

If I understood correctly the shape of train_inputs - `[batch_size]` is an array of integers, and the length of the arrays is `batch_size`. Then the shape of `train_labels` is `[batch_size, 1]`, which is the matrix  with a single row. Correct? If yes, I don't understand why it's so, and what should be stored in those placeholders. According to the theory, the `label` is a int and the `input` is an array of the sliding window of context, so why `batch_size` shows up there?

It seems like I missed something fundamental in the theory. I would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to be debugging word2vec_basic.py recently and for a simple data set example "the dog saw a cat the dog chased the cat the cat climbed a tree", `dictionary` is `{'the': 0, 'cat': 1, 'dog': 2, 'a': 3, 'saw': 4, 'chased': 5, 'climbed': 6, 'tree': 7}`, `reverse_dictionary` is `{0: 'the', 1: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 3: 'a', 4: 'saw', 5: 'chased', 6: 'climbed', 7: 'tree'}`.

When batch_size=8, skip_window=1, embedding_size=1, and num_skips=2, calling `generate_batch` returns:

`batch: [2 2 4 4 3 3 1 1]
labels: [[0] [4] [2] [3] [4] [1] [0] [3]]`

Translated to words, they are:

`batch: [dog, dog, saw, saw, a, a, cat, cat]
labels: [[the], [saw], [dog], [a], [saw], [cat], [the], [a]]`

For the first three words "the dog saw" in the data set, as skip_window is 1, the expected (target, context) pairs should be (dog, the) and (dog, saw) - see "The Skip-gram Model" in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec for more detail if needed.

As for why 1 is used in `[batch_size, 1]`, the `nce_loss` documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/nce_loss says that "labels: A Tensor of type int64 and shape [batch_size, num_true]. The target classes." and "num_true: An int. The number of target classes per training example." (num_true has a default value of 1)

And the `nce_loss` in the code is defined:

```
      loss = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,
                     biases=nce_biases,
                     labels=train_labels,
                     inputs=embed,
                     num_sampled=num_sampled,
                     num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

So now it should be easy to see the shapes of `train_inputs` and `train_labels` make sense.

Comment: Thank you very for your answer. it seems like nce_loss in batch is hard-wired to skip-grams, but in labels for some reason allows multi-label classification. Strange. And if the pairs (dog, the) and (dog, saw) I assume that the target word should appear in labels and context in batch, but it's other way round.

Answer (score 0):

For training, it is convenient to do the calculations on multiple sentences in parallel. That is the purpose of the batch_size. Each word in the batch is from a different part in the data and train_labels has the corresponding labels. The gradients are aggregated across the batch and then a single parameter update is done.

Comment: just to clarify a bit, why shape of labels is [batch_size,1] and not [batch_size] in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe there is some place where it has to be multiplied by a 1xn size matrix.